# Wordpress Search URL messing up for posts

Tags: wordpress

I set up my search in header.php, and on the main site search works properly. When I search from within a story, however, I never can get to the search results page because it tacks on the /?s=searchterm in the URL after the post slug. How can I circumvent this issue?

Comment: `$searchItem = $_GET['s']`, hope it helps.

Comment: @WereWolf-TheAlpha where exactly would I put that?

Comment: [Creating a Search Page](https://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_a_Search_Page).

Answer (score 0):

What have you provided in the action of your search form?

Use `action="<?php echo home_url( '/' ); ?>"`

I think this will solve your problem. If not provide your site url so that it would be easier to trace actual problem.